# Requests to eureka client through zuul get redirected to Tomcat home page

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to use zuul as a proxy with eureka for my spring boot microservices. On local everything is OK but when I deploy on tomcat, all  request to the proxy are redirected to Tomcat home page.
Example:
on locale : http://localhost:9090/serice-1/getAll works fine.
on cloud : 
http://xx.yy.zz.ww:8080/gateway/service-1/getAll gives 404 
http://xx.yy.zz.ww:8080/gateway/service-1/ gives Tomcat home page 
http://xx.yy.zz.ww:8080/gateway/service-1/myservice/getAll works fine

Here is my zuul service application.properties content:

```
spring.application.name=zuul-server
spring.jmx.default-domain=zuul-server
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8080/eureka/eureka
zuul.ignored-services=*
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=60000
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=10000
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=60000
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.preferSameZoneEureka=true
zuul.routes.myservice.path=/service-1/**
zuul.routes.myservice.serviceId=myservice
```

This is my GatewayApplication :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages ="com.gateway")
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients("com.gateway")
public class GatewayApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                return application.sources(GatewayApplication.class);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
        }

}
```

Maybe I am misusing some properties, but I have tried many, none have worked.